# Embedd ppt file in Iframe

Tags: html, css

Is it correct? or is there any way to do it? Can u please help me with the code?
My aim is to display my ppt file onto an i frame when i click a link.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
ul li{
       font-size: 11px;
       list-style: none;
      }
ul li a{
        text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="lightgray">

 <ul>
     <li><a href="http://docs.google.com/gview?

url=wbste/ppt/SMIME.pptx&embedded=true" target="disiframe"><font 

face="Lucida Sans" color="black" >S/MIME</font></a></li><br>
   </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you define that iframe, `src` is the iframe page source

```
<iframe name="disiframe" src="target.html"></iframe>
```

Here's a working example

```html
<body>
    <a href="http://www.wikipedia.org/" target="myIframe">Link Text</a>
    <iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/" name = "myIframe"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: How is his code correct? He does not have any <iframe> tags

Comment: @Bijan, He's code is not totally correct, what i mean is that the syntax of calling the iframe is correct, that's why i suggest him to make sure that he define that iframe.